# Delete closest element from children button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have next markup structure:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#condition-container').on('click', '.component-delete', function() {
    var component = $(this).parents('.workflow-component');
    component.closest('.hr').remove(); //Delete nothing
    //component.siblings('.hr').remove();//delete all hr but I need to delete only closest
    component.remove();
  });
});
```

```css
.widget-box {
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  margin: 3px 0;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}

.widget-box .widget-header {
  padding-right: 10px !important;
  padding-left: 10px !important;
}

.widget-header {
  padding: 0 !important;
  padding-left: 10px !important;
}

.widget-header {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 38px;
  background: #f7f7f7 repeat-x;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0, #eee 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0, #eee 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0, #eee 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff', endColorstr='#ffeeeeee', GradientType=0);
  color: #669fc7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
  padding-left: 12px;
}

.widget-body {
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.widget-toolbox {
  background-color: #EEE;
}

.widget-toolbox.padding-8 {
  padding: 8px;
}

.widget-toolbox:last-child {
  padding: 2px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCC;
}

.widget-main {
  padding: 12px;
}

.hr {
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 0;
  border-width: 1px 0 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #E3E3E3;
  margin: 12px 0;
  border-top-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .11);
}

.hr-dotted,
.hr.dotted {
  border-style: dotted;
}

.hr-18,
.hr18 {
  margin: 18px 0;
}

.hr:nth-child(3n) {
  border-color: red
}

.hr:nth-child(3n+1) {
  border-color: green
}

.hr:nth-child(3n+2) {
  border-color: blue
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="condition-container">
  <div class="widget-box workflow-component">
    <div class="widget-header"></div>
    <div class="widget-body">
      <div class="widget-main"></div>
      <div class="widget-toolbox padding-8 clearfix">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger component-delete"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-times"></i><span class="bigger-110">Delete</span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hr hr-18 dotted"></div>
  <div class="widget-box workflow-component">
    <div class="widget-header"></div>
    <div class="widget-body">
      <div class="widget-main"></div>
      <div class="widget-toolbox padding-8 clearfix">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger component-delete"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-times"></i><span class="bigger-110">Delete</span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hr hr-18 dotted"></div>
  <div class="widget-box workflow-component">
    <div class="widget-header"></div>
    <div class="widget-body">
      <div class="widget-main"></div>
      <div class="widget-toolbox padding-8 clearfix">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger component-delete"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-times"></i><span class="bigger-110">Delete</span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hr hr-18 dotted"></div>
  <div class="widget-box workflow-component">
    <div class="widget-header"></div>
    <div class="widget-body">
      <div class="widget-main"></div>
      <div class="widget-toolbox padding-8 clearfix">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger component-delete"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-times"></i><span class="bigger-110">Delete</span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hr hr-18 dotted"></div>
  <div class="widget-box workflow-component">
    <div class="widget-header"></div>
    <div class="widget-body">
      <div class="widget-main"></div>
      <div class="widget-toolbox padding-8 clearfix">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger component-delete"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-times"></i><span class="bigger-110">Delete</span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hr hr-18 dotted"></div>
  <div class="widget-box workflow-component">
    <div class="widget-header"></div>
    <div class="widget-body">
      <div class="widget-main"></div>
      <div class="widget-toolbox padding-8 clearfix">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger component-delete"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-times"></i><span class="bigger-110">Delete</span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Problem is that I want by click on button `Delete` remove closest `.hr` block, but in first case it removes nothing and in another case it remole all `.hr` blocks.

Expected behaviour:

1. If I click on second or another block's `Delete` button it must delete first upper block `.hr`
2. If I click on first element in must delete next `.hr` block.

How implement this behaviour based on code in example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to target immediately following sibling. the method `.closest()` traverses up starting with itself.

```
component.next('.hr').remove();
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('#condition-container').on('click', '.component-delete', function() {
    var component = $(this).parents('.workflow-component');
    component.next('.hr').remove(); 
    component.remove();
  });
});
```

```css
.widget-box {
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  margin: 3px 0;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}

.widget-box .widget-header {
  padding-right: 10px !important;
  padding-left: 10px !important;
}

.widget-header {
  padding: 0 !important;
  padding-left: 10px !important;
}

.widget-header {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 38px;
  background: #f7f7f7 repeat-x;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0, #eee 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0, #eee 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0, #eee 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff', endColorstr='#ffeeeeee', GradientType=0);
  color: #669fc7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
  padding-left: 12px;
}

.widget-body {
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.widget-toolbox {
  background-color: #EEE;
}

.widget-toolbox.padding-8 {
  padding: 8px;
}

.widget-toolbox:last-child {
  padding: 2px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCC;
}

.widget-main {
  padding: 12px;
}

.hr {
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 0;
  border-width: 1px 0 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #E3E3E3;
  margin: 12px 0;
  border-top-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .11);
}

.hr-dotted,
.hr.dotted {
  border-style: dotted;
}

.hr-18,
.hr18 {
  margin: 18px 0;
}

.hr:nth-child(3n) {
  border-color: red
}

.hr:nth-child(3n+1) {
  border-color: green
}

.hr:nth-child(3n+2) {
  border-color: blue
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="condition-container">
  <div class="widget-box workflow-component">
    <div class="widget-header"></div>
    <div class="widget-body">
      <div class="widget-main"></div>
      <div class="widget-toolbox padding-8 clearfix">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger component-delete"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-times"></i><span class="bigger-110">Delete</span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hr hr-18 dotted"></div>
  <div class="widget-box workflow-component">
    <div class="widget-header"></div>
    <div class="widget-body">
      <div class="widget-main"></div>
      <div class="widget-toolbox padding-8 clearfix">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger component-delete"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-times"></i><span class="bigger-110">Delete</span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hr hr-18 dotted"></div>
  <div class="widget-box workflow-component">
    <div class="widget-header"></div>
    <div class="widget-body">
      <div class="widget-main"></div>
      <div class="widget-toolbox padding-8 clearfix">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger component-delete"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-times"></i><span class="bigger-110">Delete</span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hr hr-18 dotted"></div>
  <div class="widget-box workflow-component">
    <div class="widget-header"></div>
    <div class="widget-body">
      <div class="widget-main"></div>
      <div class="widget-toolbox padding-8 clearfix">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger component-delete"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-times"></i><span class="bigger-110">Delete</span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hr hr-18 dotted"></div>
  <div class="widget-box workflow-component">
    <div class="widget-header"></div>
    <div class="widget-body">
      <div class="widget-main"></div>
      <div class="widget-toolbox padding-8 clearfix">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger component-delete"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-times"></i><span class="bigger-110">Delete</span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hr hr-18 dotted"></div>
  <div class="widget-box workflow-component">
    <div class="widget-header"></div>
    <div class="widget-body">
      <div class="widget-main"></div>
      <div class="widget-toolbox padding-8 clearfix">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger component-delete"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-times"></i><span class="bigger-110">Delete</span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```